# Sort NSMutableArray of PFObjects by creationDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

How would I sort an array of PFObjects by their creationDate? I've tried something like the following, but this does not produce the desired result.

```
 NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                 sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" 
                                             ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedEventArray = [nodeEventArray
         sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: Does this throw an exception? Should the key not be `createdAt`

Comment: are you using an array of custom objects or NSManagedObjects?

Comment: @Wain you are correct. that was the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                 sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" 
                                             ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dateDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedEventArray = [nodeEventArray
         sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Or alternatively `updatedAt` for last updated.

Answer (score 0):

Change dateDescriptor to:

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor
                                 sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self.creationDate" 
                                             ascending:YES];
```

You need to add self if you want to check properties in objects inside the array.

Comment: Have you tested this?  I think the issue is the key name is incorrect.

Comment: @danh no I haven't I assumed that the creationDate key is valid.